# fpdf.cell height parameter generates new page instead of line break

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-generation, fpdf

i ran into an issue with fpdf python library for pdf generation.
Turns out I need my pdf with dimensions [2 inches width x 1 inches height] because i need it to print a small label in zebra printer.

The following operations were executed:

- I inserted a cell in coordinates [x=0.2,y=0.1, width=0, height=0.1] (Success)
- Executed a break line (Success)
- Inserted another cell in coordinates [x=0.2,y=coordinate which break line places, width=0, height=0.1] (FAILURE). What i was expecting is the cell to be below the first cell already placed. But instead when I used a height of 0.1 for the cell,
  The pdf adds another page and then add the cell in second page.
  [Double_Page_Instead_Same_Page_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvm0Q.png)
  When i modify height=0 cell is placed below first cell without adding a new page like this
  [Cell_In_Same_Page_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hCB0.png)

I need the cells to be the height i want (in this case 0.1), because the data i am placing comes from a database and also there are at least 3 rows which i need to insert one below other.

NOTES: When increasing pdf height [2 inches width x 2 inches height] instead of [2 inches width x 1 inches height], it behaves as I expected, but i need the [2 inches width x 1 inches height] dimensions.

- Why could this behaviour be happening?
- How could i resolve this issue?

I am using:

- Windows 10 Professional.
- Python 3.8.8.
- fpdf2 2.4.2.
- Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Disable automatic page break.

Comment: Thanks, that really worked. Now I dont know how to mark your answer as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Olivier's comment i could resolve the issue by disabling automatic page break. In my code it looks like this:

```
page_size = (2, 1)
#Set page size to 2inch-width x 1inch-height
pdf = FPDF("P", "in", page_size)

pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_auto_page_break(auto=False)
```